# Auto-populating a paragraph in Google Docs based on a keyword trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How can you use google app scripts to trigger the auto-population of a paragraph based on a keyword trigger?
E.g.
I have 3 paragraphs written on the topic 'Live Commerce' - each representative of a different product offering.
Someone tells me they want one of these features - live stream functionality.
I type 'livestream' in to a google doc and it auto-populates a section I've written on livestreaming (either pulling this data from an external sheet or the same/different google doc.

Comment: What is a keyword trigger?  I'm not familiar with them

Comment: @Cooper I mean a word that acts as a trigger for an action. E.g. I assign the word 'Facebook' to a paragraph of text so that when Facebook is inputted in a section, that paragraph of text is populated. Is something like this possible?

Comment: The only trigger associated with a google doc is the onOpen.  You can see that by launching the script editor and going to the triggers section.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for simple substitutions (here meaning the replacement text can not contain any formatting, line breaks, tabs, escaped characters/wild cards, et cetera) is:

- Tools —> Preferences

Then go to the 'Substitutions' tab. There you can add a new trigger/substitution pair. The substitution can be long—I was able to use your entire post as the substitution text.

**But note:** This behaves oddly with regard to capitalisation. If you type your trigger word in lowercase, the entire substitution will be lower case. If you capitalise the entire trigger word, the substitution will be in all caps. If you capitalise only the first letter of your trigger word, the beginning of the substitution will be capitalised; however, if it is several sentences long, the capitalisation does not extend to subsequent sentences.

I am also currently looking for a more sophisticated substitution option, but maybe this will be useful to you in the meantime.